Why does pip not work when I try to install packages in PyCharm?
Basically, whenever i started to use PyCharm, i usually install all my pacakges there. For some reason, (it just started to happen), I would constantly get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.build_env'
I don't know whats going on, but its kind of annoying me right now. I can install normally on my mac terminal, but Pycharm doesnt work.
I tried to install packages in Pycahrm, and this error came: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.build_env'

Try this
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

If this does not work, for a temporary workaround, you can create a virtual environment, which will install pip for you
python3 -m venv <myenvname> 


it didn't work, its still showing the same error.

Can you try removing pip completely and then reinstalling it. Follow this link for the steps - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5373#issuecomment-387770611
